# lyx/latex adds the space symbol (␣) in the generated pdf file when importing some python code

Tags: listings, white-space

I'm writing a document with lyx and I discovered that for a particular piece of python code, the pdf generated by lyx contains the "␣" instead of a space.
Here the code:

```
\documentclass[twoside,twocolumn,italian]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=Python}

\begin{document}
test

\lstinputlisting{test.py}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image: test.png]

If I remove \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

```
\documentclass[twoside,twocolumn,italian]{article}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=Python}

\begin{document}
test

\lstinputlisting{test.py}
\end{document}
```

I get:

[image]

Python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
#
# drop gender group Unknown/Invalid
df = df.query("gender != 'Unknown/Invalid'")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to TeX SE. According to Section 1.3 of the [`listings` package documentation](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf), this is the intended, default behavior for spaces in strings. You can set the `showstringspaces` option to disable this:

```latex
\documentclass[twoside, twocolumn, italian]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=Python, showstringspaces=false}

\begin{document}
test

\lstinputlisting{test.py}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output without placeholder characters for spaces in strings]

Please refer to the aforementioned documentation for more details on this and other package options, as the documentation is quite comprehensive.

Comment: Wow totally missed that option. Thank you sir, problem solved.